# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException while deploying EAR

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, struts2, ejb-3.0

I am developing a web module in struts2 framework and ejb module in eclipse with hibernate as ORM framework.

Every time when I modify my ejb module I have to package it into jar and include it in my web module **/WEB-INF/lib** folder in order to run my whole application.

Though the application worked fine in this way but it was really time consuming. So I tried to map them in a EAR module. But when I try to run EAR module.

It gives below exceptions

```
2016-12-24 13:23:43,992 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler] (default task-4) Exception occurred during processing request: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error: javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at com.ebs.persistence.dao.UserDao.<clinit>(UserDao.java:16)
    at com.ebs.business.service.UserAuthorisationBusinessService.getUserProfile(UserAuthorisationBusinessService.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException from [Module "deployment.EBS.ear.EBS-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 179 more
```

Below is where I suspect to get the exception

```
private static SessionFactory sessfct = SessionFactoryGenerator.getSessionFactory();
```

It seems to be some issue with classloader.Somehow it is not able to load hibernatecore.jar. Earlier it use to work fine with same set of jars when EAR was not in the picture. I am new to EAR. Below is the structure of application.xml

```
<module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>EBS-web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>EBS-web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>EBS-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
```

I also tried including all the jars in EAR lib folder but no success was achieved

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing a web module in struts2 framework and ejb module in
>   eclipse with hibernate as ORM framework. Every time when I modify my
>   ejb module I have to package it into jar and include it in my web
>   module /WEB-INF/lib folder in order to run my whole application.

With an Eclipse plugin as WTP, you should not have this problem.

> I also tried including all the jars in EAR lib folder but no success
>   was achieved

If you place the JARs in the EAR, they should be in the `APP-INF/lib` folder at the root of the EAR.

Besides, you could use a build tool as Maven or Gradle. It could ease your job of packaging.